# Build active architecture only for CocoaPods needs to be NO in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

In an old project where we use cocoapods, there is a strange problem since Xcode 6: when compiling for iphone (not simulator), some random cocoapods are not found while building (e.g. Flurry). In Xcode 5 everything is fine. This is with When 'Build active architecture only = YES' in the Cocoapods target.

When 'Build active architecture only = NO', everything works as expected.

Why is this? I've already rebuilt cocoapods a few times, but it keeps the same.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Append to your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: First of all: thanks, this solves the problem I had. After I changed ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH from YES to NO in my project, I had CI builds fail, while the local working copy still built fine even after cleaning. Fresh clones didn't work either, same error as in CI. Funny how my issue seems to be the other way around as the OP, yet your code fixes this. I really don't know what's going on here or how I would have arrived at this solution.